# SciFi book from 80s or 70s with a cover having a giant golden eagle fighting a giant serpent

Tags: story-identification

Hi, I'm looking for a science fiction fantasy novel I bought for my oldest brother in the early eighties or late seventies. I am trying to find title of said book. This is all I can remember seeing as I was a very young girl and there is not much to go on:

> The cover had a giant golden eagle on front fighting a giant serpent. Two wizards were controlling them.

Answer (score 19):

Sounds like Zelazny's '[Madwand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madwand)' to me... It was published in 1981, so fits the end of your date range.

[image: Madwand]